# jQuery not working on multiple div classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with getting jQuery to work on multiple div classes. As you can see in the code, in the "container" there are multiple divs in the same position that look like b1, that hide/show based on which one is clicked. Inside each div class there are images and buttons. The buttons navigate through those images and scroll to the information section on the bottom of the page. The problem is that the jQuery for those buttons only work on the first div ".b1", all other divs (".b2" ".b3" etc) respond incorrectly. For instance, the info button that's meant to scroll down only does so in b1, in all others it scrolls up. The previous/ next button respond incorrectly and start skipping images (I won't share that code because it's quite long and complicated but hopefully I get the point across).

I don't know if the problem is in the html, css or jQuery but I've tried to change it all without a different result. Does anyone see what's going wrong?

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="b1">

            <div class="buttons">   
                <div class="previous">previous</div>
                <div class="next">next</div><br>
                <div class="info">information</div>
            </div>

            <div class="image">     
                <div class="section"><img src="example.jpg"></div>
                <div class="section"><img src="example.jpg"></div>
                <div class="section"><img src="example.jpg"></div>
                <div id="information" class="section">text</div>
            </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.a1').click(function() {  
       $(".b2, .b3, .b4, .b5, .b6, .b7, .b8, .b9, .b10, .b11").hide();     
       $('.b1').show() 
});

$(".info").click(function() {
        var $t = $(".image");
        $t.animate({"scrollTop":
            $(".image")[0].scrollHeight
            }, 500);
        return false;
});
```

css

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    left: 2.5vw;
}

.image{
    float: left;
    left: 2.5vw;
    margin-right: 2.5vw;
    height: 70vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.buttons{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8s2e2sg/

Comment: Can you please add this to a fiddle?

Comment: Here as per the code provided I can only see one issue. But I'm not sure if that resolves you issue. The image element you are targeting should be inside the main element. For example this `var $t = $(".image");` should be `var $t = $('.b1').find(".image");` (as per your parent element). If you add your code to a working fiddle then it's easier to find the exact problem.

Comment: In order for you to scroll to a specific area based on a specific button being clicked, you need to use IDs instead of classes. Since you're reusing the `previous` class (for example), the page treats you clicking any previous button the same as if you clicked the first instance of the previous class.

Comment: Here's the link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8s2e2sg/

Comment: where is the `class="a1" item you are clicking?

Comment: the class a1 is in a seperate div next to .container. I haven't included it because I don't think the problem is there, but it look like
<div class="text">
  <div class="a1">text</div><div class="a2">text</div>
</div>

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in your js in the fiddle that shows what happens when you click on previous or next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Deepak Biswal explained in the comments, you were targeting always the first `.image` which is in B1. To get it work make it look for the `.image` corresponding relative to the `.info` clicked:

```
$(".info").click(function() {
        var $t = $(this).parent().parent().find(".image");
        $t.animate({"scrollTop":
            $t[0].scrollHeight
            }, 500);
        return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8s2e2sg/1/

You could improve your code adding a common class to all the `b` sections in order to avoid using `parent().parent()`

I updated the Fiddle with some things that might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/x8s2e2sg/2/

Comment: Ah, I get the problem, I'll update that for all the buttons. Thanks for your help!